# Is there a project that implements a scheduler based on a .NET service?

Tags: .net, windows-services, scheduling

Is there an implementation of a Windows service that can call custom [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) code that can be scheduled to run on specific intervals?

Or should I implement my own (which I am currently doing), but I think it's better not to reinvent the wheel :)

I don’t want to use [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler).

Comment: Why don't you want to use the Windows scheduler?  Given that the scheduler meets the requirements you've stated so far, more explanation will help us find a better fit.

Comment: Could you share the reason not to use the Windows Task Scheduler? The reasons may be good input for providing good answers.

Comment: I'm a little confused if you are trying to execute an application at a specified interval, or call a function.

Comment: i dont want to use the windows shedular because i need more timing then is available in the schedular "like run every 30 seconds"
also i want the configuration of the schedul to be saved in the application so i can redeploy it later.
i want to call a function because calling an application will introduce some not needed overheads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just looking to call a function periodically, use [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx).  Using this, it would be easy to write a simple service that performs whatever tasks you want at your chosen intervals.

A good library for scheduling jobs is [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/).  You can either run it as a stand-alone application, or as a part of your own application.  It has a very good API with many features out of the box.  There is also a tutorial to get you started.  It is a port of the Java [Quartz](http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz) scheduling framework.

If you are looking for a replacement to the Windows Scheduler, try [VisualCron](http://www.visualcron.com/).  It's not free, but it has many features.

Comment: actually i am in the process of writing one right now but thought its better to use some open source project if its available

Comment: Updated answer to include Quartz.NET.  Definitely check it out.

Comment: quartz.net is nice but its too complex for my needs. so i think i will implement my own scheduling service :)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to develop your own Windows service application. It should not take much effort with Visual Studio. Surely you will find a sample application at MSDN or on the web.

Comment: actually its not very easy since i need to handle advanced scheduling timing options.
like run on the minute 07 every hour and repeat for 10 minutes and so on

Answer (score 0):

Try something like *[Writing a Useful Windows Service in .NET in Five Minutes [Dave Fetterman]](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396428.aspx)*.